# What Latex typing environment is best to use under Windows?

Tags: math-mode, biblatex, windows, ide

I am sure this question was asked before but please allow me to ask again, or to have an up to date feedback at least.

I actually am trying TexWorks editor / TexLive, but it doesn't quite seem practical like the online compiler Overleaf.

What other options to use under windows do we have ? 
Or what is the best environment that you use to work effectively, both to write draft notes but also to write official mathematical papers, books, or data reports ?

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. For me, I am happy with Texmaker in combination with Texlive.

Comment: But maybe use an editor that understands markdown like obsidian. Then you can later convert it to latex if needed.

Comment: The compilation time is big, and is there a way that the script itself recognize different commands so it is easy to track misspelling and errors ? I just find it is weird how Overleaf is run on the cloud but still faster and more flexible.

Comment: Have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides . Search for Windows or other keywords.

Comment: Overleaf has also the quick compile feature which makes it a lot faster. I don't see why I need to wait each time I change one formula by another, for the whole document to be compiled. Also the script in Overleaf is colored, each command is clearly visible and you don't need to stare a lot before finding out what is going on. I will check the links thank you.

Comment: surely any tex editor provides coloured syntax highlighting, even this site does. The structure of a PDF file is a single binary file with objects referenced via byte offsets within the stream, you are always going to need to re-process the entire document after an edit, you can not update one formula and re-paginate an existing PDF.

Comment: The question is closed ! it is like the problem is settled ?! Ok then, assuming the problem is solved already, which from the different (more than 30) editors here tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides I should use? Which is best? 
- @DavidCarlisle I am surprised they provide coloured syntax highlighting, I should look then how maybe activate that.
- How is the fast-compile feature works in Overleaf? It omits loading figures and slight formatting details as I noticed.

Comment: that is how the stackexchange model works, duplicate questions are discouraged as it makes it harder for people searching for "IDE" say if there are answers scattered over multiple similar questions. If there is new updated information, such as a new editor being released, it is better to add a new or updated answer to the existing post rather than have a high rep post with just old answers and newer updated answers on multiple new posts that may come much further down search results.

Comment: personally I use emacs, I have used essentially the same editor for tex, xml, C, Fortran, markdown, lisp, ... every day since 1987, but choose whichever you like.